# How can I customise the actual response in model class itself using Retrofit Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm explaining thorugh one example, so please try to understand the below scenario:

Let's say from API I'm getting this response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "hot": [
      {
        "name": "OnePlus 6 (Mirror Black 6GB RAM + 64GB memory)",
        "price": "34999",
        "image_url": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41DZ309iN9L._AC_US160_.jpg",
        "key": 2
      }
    ],
    "cold": [
      {
        "name": "OnePlus 6 (Mirror Black 6GB RAM + 64GB memory)",
        "price": "34999",
        "image_url": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41DZ309iN9L._AC_US160_.jpg",
        "value": 4
      }
    ],
    "widget": {
      "test": "Hello"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, normally using Retrofit + GSON, we use model classes like this:

**Temperature**

```
    data class Temperature(
    val `data`: Data
)
```

**Data**

```
    data class Data(
    val cold: List<Cold>,
    val hot: List<Hot>,
    val widget: Widget
)
```

**Cold**

```
data class Cold(
    val image_url: String,
    val name: String,
    val price: String,
    val value: Int
)
```

**Hot**

```
data class Hot(
    val image_url: String,
    val key: Int,
    val name: String,
    val price: String
)
```

**Widget**

```
data class Widget(
    val test: String
)
```

**Requirement**

What I want is, my model class should design differently. If I created a custom class like this:

**Widget**

```
data class Widget(
    val map: LinkedHashMap<Int, Int>
)
```

Inside this map, using Retrofit, I want that:

map key should store as: `Hot` class "key" field

map value should store as: `Cold` class "value" field

Please note, I do not want to extract data and then manually create map object, iterate loop and store it in any view or other layer class. I need something automated. May be using any converter factory?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want retrofit to do this for you instead of doing it yourself from retrofit response?

Comment: Hi @ArpitShukla Thanks for reply. So I've a large existing project with manual parsing functionality in entire app. Now I've introduced Retrofit in my existing project. Now there are so many places, for example adapter class, there I was getting hashmap object inside constructor. And I really can't change it. And also API response is also not possible to modify it because of lots of dependencies. So I'm finding a suggestion that instead of again doing manual parsing after retrofit response, there should be some automated way

Comment: So u just want retrofit to return a HashMap instead of serializing it to data classes?

Comment: @ArpitShukla Both I want, because other field I require, so serializing to data class is also necessary. And serializing to data class with hashmap is also I want

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to get both the data class and HashMap representation of a response from Retrofit at the same time, but one solution you can try is to get the data classes from Retrofit and convert them to Maps by yourself whenever you need that.

To convert a data class to a `Map<String, Any>` you can use any serialization library. Using Gson, you can use these helper functions:

```kotlin
val gson = GsonBuilder()
    .setObjectToNumberStrategy(ToNumberPolicy.LONG_OR_DOUBLE)
    .create()

//convert a data class to a map
fun <T> T.serializeToMap(): Map<String, Any> {
    return convert()
}

//convert a map to a data class
inline fun <reified T> Map<String, Any>.toDataClass(): T {
    return convert()
}

//convert an object of type I to type O
inline fun <I, reified O> I.convert(): O {
    val json = gson.toJson(this)
    return gson.fromJson(json, object : TypeToken<O>() {}.type)
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
val temperature = // Your Temperature data class that you received from Retrofit
val map = temperature.serializeToMap()
```

Comment: Nope. it is not that entire data class should convert as map. Basically from 2 nested object, Retrofit should take key, value and it should add in parent object as a map field, something like that

Comment: Are those `2 nested object` always gonna be the same i.e. for all requests? Can you add the final output format that you expect in the question?

Comment: Arpit, I've given you one example. Actual response will be completely different and for all diff request, responses will be very. My simple question is. From the entire response, from one place I want key, and from other place I want value, and from inside any other object I want readymade map, how can I achieve that?

Comment: If you speak about final output then, inside my question dummy response, there were no map coming right?, but let's say inside widget model class, I added one map field. So Retrofit should store expected key and value inside that field while parsing itself

Comment: `from one place I want key, and from other place I want value` That's what I am asking. Do you want to specify these two `places` yourself for every request because if these aren't the same across all requests, how will Retrofit know which key to use? (Btw I don't think there is any simple way to achieve what you are trying to do. Retrofit doesn't parse the response by itself, it uses a separate parsing library like Gson, Moshi etc that we provide. Changing the parsing logic isn't a trivial task.)

Comment: Yea even I'm already using Gson that's not a problem. And why you're thinking for every request? For every request model classes should be different. Or if we've to do changes in retrofit code, in that case we can put some URL match type of condition

Comment: Yes, that 2 desired places shoule be vary from req to req and it depends upon my use case. I should decide that